# How to fix setuptools outdated on google cloud ml-engine job

Tags: google-cloud-ml

Training job fails with gcloud ml-engine training job.
Solutions tried:

- Updated setuptools, pip and wheel to latest version on Google
  cloud sdk shell
- Removed and reinstalled setuptools, pip and wheel on local machine
- Updated setuptools, pip and wheel to latest version on Google
  cloud terminal
- reinstalled cloud sdk tools on local machine

```
Trackback (most recent call last):
    [...]
      return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps) 
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",line 666, in install_item
      dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",line 856, in install_eggs
      return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
line 1078, in build_and_install
      self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
line 1063, in run_setup
      run_setup(setup_script, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 68, in r
un_setup
      DirectorySandbox(setup_dir).run(runner)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 114, in
run
      return func()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 67, in r
unner
      _execfile(setup_script, ns)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 43, in _
execfile
      exec(code, globals, locals)
File "/tmp/easy_install-Pe5fZg/pytest-runner-4.2/setup.py", line 76, in <mod
ule> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 266, in __init__
      _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
      self.finalize_options()    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 301, in fin
alize_options
      ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools_scm/integration.py", line 10,
in version_keyword
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools_scm/version.py", line 66, in _
warn_if_setuptools_outdated
SetuptoolsOutdatedWarning: your setuptools is too old (<12)
```

Setup.py

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['keras','hickle','scipy','numpy']

setup(
    name='trainer',
    version='1.0',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='My training application package.'
)
```

Config.yaml

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: BASIC_GPU
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I marked your error message as code block with <!-- language: lang-none --> so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting.  Good luck!

Comment: Could you please share your `setup.py` file with the Python requirements for your job? The machines used when running on ML Engine install packages based on the requirements you provide. They don't detect the versions from the cloud shell or your local machine.

Comment: @rpasricha I have included the setup.py file and config.yaml.

Comment: Ah this looks like an issue with the setuptools installed on your local machine or in your virtual environment. Could you try running `pip install --upgrade setuptools pip` and submitting your job again?